# WordPress RestAPI отображается в нечитабельном виде

Tags: wordpress, api, wordpress-плагины

Привет, я решил натянуть свой fron-end на WordPress используя RestApi но отображения Json масива в браузере не совсем адекватное,оно все в одну строчку.Как мне сделать чтобы отображалось в отступами(в более читабельном формате)?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Нажать на фигурные скобки внизу, где написано Line:1 Column: xxxx

Comment: Пробовал, не помогает.

Comment: Ну а на синий текст show в строке Pretty-print this minified file?

Answer (score 1):

Если вам нужно просматривать json в отформатированном виде прямо в браузере (у вас Google Chrome), то вам необходимо скачать и установить соответствующее расширение. Как пример, такое: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/json-formatter/bcjindcccaagfpapjjmafapmmgkkhgoa?hl=ru